# Attribute "orientation" has already been defined when using GridLayout & ConstraintLayout together

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, android-constraintlayout

While using GridLayout and ConstraintLayout together i get the following error

```
Error:(115) Attribute "orientation" has already been defined
```

The problem is because both of the libraries use this

```
<attr name="orientation">
```

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in `ConstraintLayout` 1.0.0-alpha2 ([release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available)).
Update your dependency to:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is already reported and probably fixed in the upcoming version of CL: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210511

As for a workaround, I found none but disabling either layout :/